# 3d wave reflection with neumann boundary condition

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Solve the equation in the half-space $\left\{ (x,y,z,t): z > 0 \right\}$ with the Neumann condition $\frac{\partial u}{\partial z} = 0$ on $z=0$ , and with initial data $\phi (x,y,z) \equiv 0$ and general $\psi(x,y,z)$.

So far, I have:

Given Kirchhoff's formula $\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\mathbf{#1}} u(\vec{x}, t_{0}) = \frac{1}{4 \pi c^{2} t_{0}} \iint_S \psi(\vec{x}) \,dS + \frac{\partial}{\partial t_{0}} \left[ \frac{1}{4 \pi c^{2} t_{0} }\iint_{S} \phi (\vec{x}) \,dS \right]$

For the initial condition reduces to $\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\mathbf{#1}} u(\vec{x}, t_{0}) = \frac{1}{4 \pi c^{2} t_{0}} \iint_S \psi(\vec{x}) \,dS \,$

Using an even extension of $\psi$

\begin{equation}
\psi = \begin{cases} \psi(x,y,z) & \mbox{if } z>0 \\ \psi(x,y,-z) & \mbox{if } z<0
 \end{cases}
\end{equation}

Which gives

$u(x,y,z,t) = \frac{1}{4 \pi c^2 t} \iint_{\partial B( \{x,y,z\}, ct)} \psi(x,y,z) \, dS$ for $z>0$

$u(x,y,z,t) = \frac{1}{4 \pi c^2 t} \iint_{\partial B( \{x,y,-z\}, ct)} \psi(x,y,-z) \, dS$ for $z<0$

Is this all I have to do? I'm not sure if I'm using the extension correctly in the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the letter $\psi$ for  both $\psi$ and the extension of $\psi$. So it's not clear what the formulas involving $\psi$ mean. Let $\tilde \psi$ denote the extended function:
$$
\tilde \psi(x,y,z) = \begin{cases} \psi(x,y,z) & \mbox{if } z>0 \\ \psi(x,y,-z) & \mbox{if } z<0
 \end{cases}
$$

In the integral formula for $u$, you use $x,y,z$ on the left but also as variables of integration. This again is a misuse of notation: you are saying that the integral is taken over all points $(x,y,z)$ at distance  $ct$ from the point $(x,y,z)$... This would be correct:

$$u(x,y,z,t) = \frac{1}{4 \pi c^2 t} \iint_{\partial B( \{x,y,z\}, ct)} \tilde \psi(x',y',z') \, dS$$

Finally, if you want to express the integral in terms of the original $\psi$, consider that the sign of $z'$ need not be the sign of $z$. When the region of integration crosses the plane of reflection, things get more complicated.

You could write 
$$u(x,y,z,t) = \frac{1}{4 \pi c^2 t} \iint_{\partial B( \{x,y,z\}, ct)\cap \{z'>0\}}   \psi(x',y',z') \, dS\\ +\frac{1}{4 \pi c^2 t} \iint_{\partial B( \{x,y,z\}, ct)\cap \{z'<0\}}   \psi(x',y',-z') \, dS$$

(Also, note that the final answer should be stated only for $z>0$, because this is the domain in which the problem is posed.)

The second integral is zero (due to empty region of integration) when $z>ct$.